# Counting data from array in object php

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I'm new in php.

When i `print_r($documents)`, the system will display:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [title] => "AAA" [summary] => blablabla [score] => 100 [topic] => Technology ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [title] => "BBB" [summary] => blablabla [score] => 86 [topic] => Food ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [title] => "CCC" [summary] => blablabla [score] => 45 [topic] => Technology ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [title] => "DDD" [summary] => blablabla [score] => 67 [topic] => Technology ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [title] => "EEE" [summary] => blablabla [score] => 88 [topic] => Technology ))

I want to count 'topic' and find a highest 'score' on that object, so i have a result:

> Topic "Technology" = 4 documents
>
> Topic "Food" = 1 document
>
> Highest score = 100 in document "AAA"

What can i do with foreach function?

```
foreach($documents as $data)
{
    $id = $data->id;
    $title = $data->title;
    $score = $data->score;
    $topic = $data->topic;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$top   = $documents[0]; // top element (with max score, assume first one as default)
$group = array();       // group buffer to store document count

foreach($documents as $data){
   $topic = $data->topic;

   // if topic in group
   if(isset($group[$topic])){
       $group[$topic]++;   // add one document
   } else { // otherwise
       $group[$topic] = 1; // set one document
   }

   // if $tops's score value is lesser than current $data's value
   if($top->score < $data->score){
       $top = $data; // there is a new top.
   }
}

var_dump($group, $top);
```

You may aquire any property of `$top` object. Also you have group count for each topic in `$group` array.